# Strip duplicate parameters from the url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to strip duplicate query string parameters from the url. What am I doing wrong?

```
function stripUrlParams(url, parameter) {
    //prefer to use l.search if you have a location/link object
    var urlparts= url.split('?');   
    if (urlparts.length>=2) {

        var prefix= encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
        var pars= urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

        //reverse iteration as may be destructive
        for (var i= pars.length; i-- > 0;) {    
            //idiom for string.startsWith
            if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) {  
                pars.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        url = urlparts[0] + '?' + pars.join('&');
        return url;
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}
```

stripUrlParams('www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2&x=2');
//Should return "www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2".

http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/LnzsoLot/1/

Comment: I don't get it. You want to remove parameters with same values, or in your example it should be 'www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2&y=2' (y instead of x) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function stripUrlParams(url, parameter) {
    //prefer to use l.search if you have a location/link object
    var urlparts= url.split('?');   
    if (urlparts.length>=2) {

        var stuff = urlparts[1];
        pars = stuff.split("&");
        var comps = {};
        for (i = pars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            spl = pars[i].split("=");
            comps[spl[0]] = spl[1];
        }
        pars = [];
        for (var a in comps)
            pars.push(a + "=" + comps[a]);
        url = urlparts[0] + '?' + pars.join('&');
        return url;
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}

document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = stripUrlParams('www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2&x=2');
//Should return "www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2".
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/n8497sqL/**

Answer (score 0):

In your var `var prefix= encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';`, `parameter` is undefined.

Try to provide a value for it, and this will probably solve your issue by adding your 2nd param in your function call:

```
stripUrlParams('www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2&x=2', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: Your function does not remove duplicate URL arguments, it simply removes the `parameter` you pass to the method when you call it.

For example calling

```
stripUrlParams('www.testurl.com?x=1&y=2&x=2', 'x');
```

will strip all `x` parameters from the URL. You'll have to keep track of parameters that are in your URL already and remove them (or not copy them over), when you come across them a second time. Possible solutions have been provided in other answers already.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution from @Praveen Kumar is good but its will not correctly handle if the multi-selection values or arrays are passed.

So I'm writing here a function with little changes the function is to be used with URI instead of full URL, just pass this part to this function `x=1&y=2`.

```
function stripUriParams(uri) {
    var stuff = decodeURIComponent(uri);
    var pars = stuff.split("&");
    var finalPars = [];
    var comps = {};
    for (var i = pars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        spl = pars[i].split("=");
        //ignore arrays
        if(!spl[0].endsWith(']')) {
            comps[spl[0]] = spl[1];
        } else {
            //this is array so enter it into final url array
            finalPars.push(spl[0] + "=" + spl[1]);
        }
    }
    for (var a in comps)
        finalPars.push(a + "=" + comps[a]);
    url = finalPars.join('&');
    return url;
}
```

Input:

```
stripUriParams('pr1=2&pr1=3&pr2=1&arr[]=1&arr[]=2');
```

Output:

```
pr1=2&pr2=1&arr[]=1&arr[]=2
Whereas the output of Parveen's function would be something like 
pr1=2&pr2=1&arr[]=1
```

PS) Why I didn't edit the above answer because I modified it for URIs instead of full URL.